# Why is my for loop containing a fetch API call only running once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, scope, fetch

I have a loop to verify up to 5 `ids` if they actually exist. I have a for loop that iterates over the `ids`, makes a call to the endpoint to check, and does some functionality with the results.

The problem I am having is that the loop is only running one time then seems to return out of the function. My function is as follows:

```
isValidAIN(ains) {
  var control = this;
  var length = ains.length;

  //length is logging correctly when the function is called.
  console.log("length: ", length);

  if (length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      //this runs once only
      console.log("i: ", i);
      if (ains[i].length !== 10) {
        //this doesn't run
        console.log("length: ", ains[i].length);
        console.log("object in length: ", ains[i].length);
        console.log(ains[i]);

        if (ains[i].length === 0) {
          this.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "";
          this.state.validAINS[i] = true;
        } else {
          this.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "This AIN Number Must Contain 10 Digits";
          this.state.validAINS[i] = false;
        }
        this.setState(this.state);
      } else {
        //this log only runs once
        console.log("this should run for every iteration but only runs once");

        fetch("/myendpoint/?ain=" + ains[i])
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
              console.log("success: ", result);

              if (result == null) {
                //This logs to 0 for the first iteration and then does not repeat. I am purposely entering invalid ids to hit this area.
                console.log("i: ", i);

                control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "AIN Is Invalid";
                control.state.validAINS[i] = false;
                control.setState(control.state);
              } else {
                //not hitting this area 
                console.log("res: ", result);
                control.state.errors["ain[" + i + "]"] = "";
                control.state.validAINS[i] = true;
                control.setState(control.state);
              }
            },
            (error) => {
              //not hitting this area
              console.log("error: ", error);
            }
          )
      }
    }
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are mutating your state all over the place (`this.state.something = ...`). Use [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) without mutating the current state instead. And are you sure the `ains[i].length !== 10` check fails for all ids, so that the fetch is actually run for all ids?

Comment: I can't use setState with a variable like that I don't believe.                                      ex:    this.setState{( validAINS[i] : true }); the object format does not like those variables in there. And yes I am sure that length is failing I added a console log and also added a log at the top of the for loop to log i on every iteration and it is only running once.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so it will be easier to help you.

Comment: this code pen is throwing some errors though not sure if its because that endpoint is not working through code pen though

Comment: https://snag.gy/GeSn7i.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized my mistake in this commenting the code out line by line. The `validAINS` array was initialized as an empty array but never actually initialized with values. So the api call had nothing to do with the problem but trying to set the indexes of the empty array to values was breaking the loop. Initializing the array in `ComponentDidMount` function fixed the issue.